# when ajax post success i want to refresh a particular <div> in page

Tags: ajax, html, jquery

i want to refresh a particular div on ajax success, im using the below code but the whole page getting refreshed.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#post_submit').click(function() {
  var form_data = {
    csrfsecurity: $("input[name=csrfsecurity]").val(),
    post_text: $('#post_text').val()    
  };

  $.ajax({
    url: "<?php echo site_url('/post_status'); ?>",
    type: 'POST',
    data: form_data,
    success: function(response){
      $(".home_user_feeds").html("markUpCreatedUsingResponseFromServer");
    }
    return false;
  });
  return false;
});
</script>
```

Comment: `$('#post_submit')` - is this a form submit button?

Comment: yes it is a submit button

Comment: also i want to know what is 'markUpCreatedUsingResponseFromServer' in above code

Answer (score 1):

you have an extra `return false` which is inside the `$.ajax` block which most probably causes an error so your form isn't submitted via ajax.  If you remove that, you shouldn't have any issues.

Comment: also i want to know what is 'markUpCreatedUsingResponseFromServer' in above code

Comment: that should be just `response`. `$(".home_user_feeds").html(response)`

Answer (score 0):

Use the `submit` event of the form and remove the `return false` from the ajax callback:

```
$('#myFormId').on('submit', function() {

    var form_data = {
        csrfsecurity: $("input[name=csrfsecurity]").val(),
        post_text: $('#post_text').val()    
    };

    $.ajax({
        url: "<?php echo site_url('/post_status'); ?>",
        type: 'POST',
        data: form_data,
        success: function(response){
            $(".home_user_feeds").html("markUpCreatedUsingResponseFromServer");
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: also i want to know what is 'markUpCreatedUsingResponseFromServer' in above code

Answer (score 0):

Remove the return false from inside your $.ajax function. Its a syntax error. The $.ajax function only expects a json object as an argument. "return false" cannot be part of a json object. You should keep the JavaScript console open during testing at all times - Press Ctrl-Shift-J in Chrome and select console to see any JS errors.

Also suggest you use `<input type=button>` instead of `<input type=submit>` or `<button></button>`